# Markdown in Neovim: which plugin sets conceallevel=2?

Tags: neovim, filetype-markdown, conceal

I'm experiecing the most annoying thing ever: when I edit a markdown file, asterisk characters are hidden by default.

If I set on an open buffer `:set conceallevel=0`, asterisks shows up as they should, but if I put this conf in my `init.vim` file, it does not work anymore.

How to solve that?
And more important, **is there a way to know which plugin override my configuration**?

Thank you.

Comment: That's an expected behavior, it should make you text bold. Could it be that your terminal or colorscheme are not playing well and it is annoying that the asterisks just disappear? By the way, anychance you have the Vimwiki plugin configured to use markdown? You might find this useful: https://github.com/mhinz/vim-galore#debugging-1

Comment: No issues with the terminal. I open the file: no asterisks and bold text between pairs of invisible asterisks. Then I set `conceallevel=0` on the open buffer: asterisks appear and no more bold text. The latter is the default I want, but if I put it in my `init.vim` it does not work. With `nvim -u NONE -N` it works like expected: I can see asterisks.

Comment: What about: ```augroup filetype_markdown
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType md setlocal conceallevel=0
augroup END```

Comment: It does not work: asterisk are still hidden...

Comment: Have you put the augroup on your `init.vim` and resourced or reopened neovim?

Comment: I've copy/pasted the code line you wrote above inside `init.vim`, closed neovim, reopened neovim: nothing different happened.

Comment: After doing that, what is the output of `set filetype?` and `set conceallevel?` ? And what is the extension of your markdown file? The command assumes that you are using `*.md`.

Comment: My file has extension *.md. `set filetype?` says `markdown` and `set conceallevel?` says `conceallevel=2`...

Comment: Thanks for answering the questions. And sorry for not being able to help. Please, consider editing your question and providing more informations. You ask which plugin but you don't provide your `init.vim` or minimal sample of your configuration. And have you read the first link I sent to you? There you will have an idea about how to track that issue down. (:

Comment: Ok, you're right lsdrg. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To help answer your original question, you can check where a setting was last set with the `:verbose` command.

```
:verbose set conceallevel
```

This will display a message similar to:

```
conceallevel=2
    Last set from ~/.vim/plugged/indentLine/after/plugin/indentLine.vim
```

Note that `:verbose` simply runs a command with a specified verbosity, so if you wish to check something like the `number` setting, you'll need to run `:verbose set number?` (with the `?`, otherwise it will just turn the setting on). Check `:h :verbose` for more.

Answer (score 11):

Ok, I found the plugin involved into this: is [indentLine](https://github.com/Yggdroot/indentLine).
It is reported in its README: it does not work if `conceallevel` is not set to 1 or 2, so it set this parameter to 2 by default.

The side effect is that markdown files are terribly displayed, and you cannot edit them confortably...

I found it out debugging my `init.vim` thanks to *lsrdg* [link suggestion](https://github.com/mhinz/vim-galore#debugging-1).

---

**Update**: I solved my problem avoiding IndentLine to start for Markdown files, putting the following in my *init.vim*:

```
autocmd FileType markdown let g:indentLine_enabled=0
```

Answer (score 10):

Like @caneta, the `indentLine` plugin was the culprit for me too. I solved it by disabling it for `markdown` files like this:

```
let g:indentLine_fileTypeExclude = ['markdown']
```

Comment: This was the option that best worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Or create a Toggle mapping:

```
nnoremap <Leader>c :let &cole=(&cole == 2) ? 0 : 2 <bar> echo 'conceallevel ' . &cole <CR>
```

I am using the abbreviated form of conceallevel *cole* to make my line shorter

We can also test if the plugin indentline is loaded and then...

```
if match(&runtimepath, 'indentline') != -1
    let g:indentLine_fileTypeExclude = ['markdown']
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

[vimwiki](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki) also sets `conceallevel` as well:

```
*g:vimwiki_conceallevel*

In Vim 7.3 'conceallevel' is local to the current window, thus if you open a
Vimwiki buffer in a new tab or window, it would be set to the default value.

Vimwiki sets 'conceallevel' to g:vimwiki_conceallevel every time a Vimwiki
buffer is entered.

With default settings, Vimwiki conceals one-character markers, shortens long
URLs and hides markers and URL for links that have a description.

Default: 2

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*g:vimwiki_conceal_onechar_markers*

Control the concealment of one-character markers.

Setting 'conceal_onechar_markers' to 0 will show the markers, overriding
whatever value is set in |g:vimwiki_conceallevel|

Default: 1

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If you don't want Vimwiki to conceal markers, add the following line to your `.vimrc`:

`let g:vimwiki_conceallevel=0`